# Jquery.Validate error message on top of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I was wondering how to display a single error message above the form instead of individual field messages. like this form has http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/marketo/step2.htm

I know it has something to do with handles but not exactly sure how or where to put them

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#valform").validate();
    });
    </script>
```

this is the code i have that uses all default validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `invalidHandler` for this functionality. Something like this should do:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();

        if (errors) {
            $("#error-message").show().text("You missed " + errors + " field(s)");
        } else {
            $("#error-message").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/KheRr/1/

If you want to hide the default error messages, you should specify `""` as the error message for the field and validation type:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();

        if (errors) {
            $("#error-message").show().text("You missed " + errors + " field(s)");
        } else {
            $("#error-message").hide();
        }
    },
    messages: {
        field1: {
            required: "" // You'll have to do this for each field and validation type.
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/KheRr/2/

Comment: thanks, one more thing, how do i hide the default error messages that show on each field?